# How can I get a specific field into Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function which is called when I push an Upload Button. It should create a collection in Firestore called **userPosts** with `postId`, `ownerId`, and `mediaUrl`. Everything is working except **username** because I have to take it from another collection in Firestore called **users**. So I have this error: **Unhandled Exception:** **Invalid argument: Instance of 'Future <String>'** How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
final postsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');

createPostInFirestore({required String mediaUrl}) {
    postsRef.doc(user!.uid).collection("userPosts").doc(postId).set({
      "postId": postId,
      "ownerId": user!.uid,
      "username": userRef.doc(user!.uid).get().then((snapshot) {
        return snapshot.data()!['username'].toString();
      }),
      "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
      "timestamp": timestamp,
      "likes": {},
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `get()` and `set()` methods are asynchronous ( needs time to resolve ), so we need to make the function asynchronous with the `async` keyword, then wait to get the username, after that, wait to update the data with `set()`.
try this:

```
   final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final postsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');

  Future<void> createPostInFirestore({required String mediaUrl}) async {
    final username = await userRef.doc(user!.uid).get().then((snapshot) {
        return (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)!['username'].toString();
      });
    await postsRef.doc(user!.uid).collection("userPosts").doc(postId).set({
      "postId": postId,
      "ownerId": user!.uid,
      "username": username,
      "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
      "timestamp": timestamp,
      "likes": {},
    });
  }
```

then on the `onPressed` or the method which will execute this function, you need to wait for it also like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
await createPostInFirestore("your string URL here");
}
```

now it will work fine

Comment: No way you are helping me again ! Thanks a lot man

Comment: I added explanation to it

Comment: That's perfect, why the <void> ?

Comment: because the method doesn't return anything, it executes a piece of code

Comment: actually, the method will work fine without it but it's recommended to set types and void for void methods for better read of code

Comment: Okay I get it, and the Map<String, dynamic> can you explain it ? @Gwhyyy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249541/discussion-between-boatti-and-gwhyyy).

Comment: becasue this is it's type, in some cases Firestore returns the data() as Object? that dart don't know that it's exactly a Map<String, dynamic> so some future error may be throws due to Firestore's loose types